# Remove a div using a button created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am doing a to-do list with JavaScript. I want to **delete a div with a button, which is created dynamically with JavaScript.** I already assigned a **id** to that button but i don't know how to access it. Can anyone help ?
My code below:-

```js
var Addnew = document.querySelector('#add_new');
var myDiv;
var button;

function newDiv() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    myDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var userEntry = document.querySelector('.newIn').value;
    button = document.createElement('button');
    myDiv.className = 'item';
    myDiv.style.display = 'block';
    myDiv.innerHTML = userEntry;
    button.style.display = 'block';
    button.innerHTML = "Remove";
    button.setAttribute('id','Remove');
    button.style.marginLeft = '280px';
    button.style.background = 'tomato';
    button.style.color = 'white';
    myDiv.appendChild(button);
    body.appendChild(myDiv);
}
document.getElementById('Remove').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('done');
});

Addnew.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newDiv();
});
document.querySelector('.newIn').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        newDiv();
    }
});
```

```css
.input_box{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7%;
}
.input_box > input {
  width:250px;
}
#add_new{
  background-color:rgb(44, 147, 124);
  color:white;
  width:70px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family:sans-serif;;
}
.item{
  width:270px;
  height:35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left:38%;
  display: none;
  border: 0.5px ridge green;
}
#Remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To-do List</title>
    <!-- Css linking -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
    <div class="input_box">
      <input type="text" class="newIn" placeholder="What do you want to add?" autofocus="autofocus"/>
      <button id="add_new">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item"></div> <button id="Remove"></button>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using 'onclick' events?

Comment: onclick is just another way to do it. Click event is working fine.i want to insert value entered by user into the div.

Comment: You should use the text attribute not the innerHtml then

Comment: Are u talking about textContent? i tried that too.its not working.

Answer (score 0):

you have use query selector with class syntax, try to add with the # it should work fine as expected

var userEntry = document.querySelector('#newIn').value;

Comment: i changed that. But I want to remove the div when Remove button is clicked.

Comment: I changed that but  i only want to know how to select the button i created and delete a div with it.

Comment: document.getElementById('Remove').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('done');
});

Comment: you can try to add bellow line in to the end of newDiv function since event is attaching aftre the element is added to the DOM, and sorry about the above comment
button.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log('done'); });

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Addnew = document.querySelector('#add_new');
var myDiv;
var button;

function newDiv() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    myDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var userEntry = document.querySelector('.newIn').value;
    button = document.createElement('button');
    myDiv.className = 'item';
    myDiv.style.display = 'block';
    myDiv.innerHTML = userEntry;
    button.style.display = 'block';
    button.innerHTML = "Remove";
    button.setAttribute('id','Remove');
    button.style.marginLeft = '280px';
    button.style.background = 'tomato';
    button.style.color = 'white';
    myDiv.appendChild(button);
    body.appendChild(myDiv);
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('done');
   });

}


Addnew.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newDiv();
});
document.querySelector('.newIn').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        newDiv();
    }
});
```

```css
.input_box{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7%;
}
.input_box > input {
  width:250px;
}
#add_new{
  background-color:rgb(44, 147, 124);
  color:white;
  width:70px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family:sans-serif;;
}
.item{
  width:270px;
  height:35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left:38%;
  display: none;
  border: 0.5px ridge green;
}
#Remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To-do List</title>
    <!-- Css linking -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
    <div class="input_box">
      <input type="text" class="newIn" placeholder="What do you want to add?" autofocus="autofocus"/>
      <button id="add_new">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item"></div> <button id="Remove"></button>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var Addnew = document.querySelector('#add_new');
var myDiv;
var button;

function newDiv() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    myDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var userEntry = document.querySelector('.newIn').value;
    button = document.createElement('button');
    myDiv.className = 'item';
    myDiv.style.display = 'block';
    myDiv.innerHTML = userEntry;
    button.style.display = 'block';
    button.innerHTML = "Remove";
    button.setAttribute('id','Remove');
    button.style.marginLeft = '280px';
    button.style.background = 'tomato';
    button.style.color = 'white';
    myDiv.appendChild(button);
    body.appendChild(myDiv);
}
document.getElementById('Remove').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('done');
});

Addnew.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newDiv();
});
document.querySelector('.newIn').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        newDiv();
    }
});
```

```css
.input_box{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7%;
}
.input_box > input {
  width:250px;
}
#add_new{
  background-color:rgb(44, 147, 124);
  color:white;
  width:70px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family:sans-serif;;
}
.item{
  width:270px;
  height:35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left:38%;
  display: none;
  border: 0.5px ridge green;
}
#Remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To-do List</title>
    <!-- Css linking -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
    <div class="input_box">
      <input type="text" class="newIn" placeholder="What do you want to add?" autofocus="autofocus"/>
      <button id="add_new">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item"></div> <button id="Remove"></button>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```